# Programming ESP8266 NodeMCU Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Does any body know if I can program an interruption on the ESP8266 Node MCU Lua with Arduino's IDE (without using an Arduino)?
I need to use an interruption to work with a caudalimeter.

Any body have a datasheet of it?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand what you're asking for. NodeMCU (Lua) and Arduino core for the ESP8266 are both completely independent firmwares based on the same SDK from Espressif. So, you either flash the NodeMCU firmware and write Lua scripts or you work with the Arduino IDE and always flash a complete binary (SDK plus your program) to the device.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I understand your question.. You were looking for a way to program the NodeMCU via the arduino IDE:

If so, its pretty quick..
In the arduino IDE add this[image]: http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json to the additional boards URL, then import one of the example sketches to make it blink or whatnot.. I recall having to hold the reset button or something when doing the upload (flashing) the firmware.

NodeMCU interrupt, looks like you can do interrupts with it: http://www.electronicwings.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-gpio-interrupts-with-arduino-ide

I've played with a bunch of these: https://www.adafruit.com/product/828?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8YXXBRDXARIsAMzsQuX_fXd8wY1_LWfhPD1aUua6gN2preqnNGRR9ESCCH8aCKN5_NL0okgaAvuQEALw_wcB,
Happy to share some code if you want to chat more.